# Multiplying a rank 3 tensor with a rank 2 tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Given a rank 3 tensor:

```
sentence_max_length = 5
batch_size = 3
n_hidden = 10
n_classes = 2
x = tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(150),(batch_size,sentence_max_length, n_hidden)), dtype = tf.float32)
```

And a rank 2 tensor:

```
W = tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(20), (n_hidden, n_classes)), dtype = tf.float32)
```

And a rank 1 bias tensor:

```
b = tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(5), (n_classes), dtype = tf.float32))
```

I was wondering how one would the last two axis of `x` by `W` such that the resulting vector `Z` would be of shape `(batch_size, max_length, n_classes)` though batch_size would not be known during graph creation I've just given it a value here for demonstration purposes

So to clarify:

`Z[0] = tf.matmul(x[0,:,:], W) + b`

So that the `W` and `b` are shared across all the batches. The reason for this is that I am trying to use the `output` of `tf.dynamic_rnn` whereby the output is of shape `(batch_size, sentence_max_length, n_hidden)` and build another layer ontop of `output` which has shared weights `W` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be ...

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.layers.core import Dense

sentence_max_length = 5
batch_size = 3
n_hidden = 10
n_classes = 2
x = tf.constant(np.reshape(np.arange(150),(batch_size,sentence_max_length, n_hidden)), dtype = tf.float32)

linear_layer = Dense(n_classes, use_bias=True) #required projection value
z = linear_layer(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    res = sess.run(z)

res.shape
(3, 5, 2)
```

Internally, Dense layer creates trainable W & b variables. And, it uses standard_ops.tensordot operation to transform the last dimension to the projected value. For further details, refer to the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/layers/core.py).